# .htaccess redirect all pages under a folder to new domain

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect

I have some files placed under a particular folder in my old domain like this:
http://www.olddomain.com/folder1/.

I want to redirect all requests that try to access files under this folder to a new domain.
Example:
http://www.olddomain.com/folder1/page1.html -> http://www.newdomain.com/page1.html

How do I accomplish this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder1(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Your suggestion worked just that we need to replace olddomain with newdomain.

Comment: Glad to help!  If you could accept the answer I'd appreciate it =)