# redirect all pages from specific folder to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some files placed under a particular folder in my old domain like this: `http://www.olddomain.com/oldfolder/.` I want to redirect all requests that try to access files under this folder to a new domain. Example: `http://www.olddomain.com/oldfolder/page.html` => `http://www.newdomain.com/page.html` I tried from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416042/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-under-a-folder-to-new-domain) but it's not redirecting me to new domain. what would I do to troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/(.+)$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

Or

```
Redirect 301 /oldfolder/ http://newdomain.com/
```

Comment: OMG.. awesome buddy. Thanks a ton. Could you please tell me why my redirection rule was not working ?

Comment: @Rahul maybe mod-rewrite isnt enabled on your server.