# Redirect anything in a specific directory to a different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've just upgraded to a WordPress website and moved my old ASPX files to a different domain. Now I need anything in `http://www.example.com/subdir/$` to redirect to `http://a.example.com/subdir/$`. Everything else must remain, of course.

The closest I have gotten is placing the following in a sub-directory called `subdir` but this redirects `http://www.example.com/subdir/one/two.aspx` to `http://a.example.com/one/two.aspx` – strips the `subdir` part.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir$
RewriteRule ^/?subdir/(.*)$ http://a.example.com/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: There is either another .htaccess in the parent folder, or aspx site is doing the stripping

Comment: Yes, there is an .htaccess in the root, for WordPress permalinks, forced www and a custom user-friendly URL rewrite. I've tried moving the intructions to the .htaccess in the root and deleting the subdir directory but now there is nothing – just a WordPress 404.

Comment: I also tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416042/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-under-a-folder-to-new-domain, but it still strips the subdir part. It's not the ASPX server because I tried on a different domain I own. Same thing. Feel like it's my error with the .htaccess code.

Comment: can you share the .htaccess from parent folder?

Comment: @DusanBajic – http://pastebin.com/tANBWQyU. `go.php` is a custom form processor.

Comment: If it helps, the redirect is for the Kentico getmedia manager.

Comment: Can you change the line 5 to `RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://a.example.com/subdir/$1 [L,R=301]` and try

Comment: @DusanBajic: Yes, it worked! Please add an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this RewriteRule in your main (parent) `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://a.example.com/subdir/$1 [L,R=301]
```