# .htaccess rules to move a subfolder to a new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to permanently move everything is in my /blog/ subfolder, into a new domain, keeping the full remaining url.

i.e.:

```
- from: https//www.example.com/blog/2018/05/07/article1
- to:   https://www.newdomain/2018/05/07/article1
```

In other words, `https://www.example.com/blog` should redirect to `https://www.newdomain.com/` keeping the rest of the url unchanged.
I am getting lost with the .htaccess rules to accomplish this, without loosing SEO ranks and without interfering with other WordPress htaccess rules...

Comment: May be duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416042/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-under-a-folder-to-new-domain

Comment: is it applicable to https too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `blog/.htaccess` you can have this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* https://www.newdomain.com/$0 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: are you sure about the $0? Isn't it $1?

Comment: No it is `$0` because of no captured groups in regex pattern.